# Broadcast error rlp: non-canonical integer (leading zero bytes) for uint64

Tags: transactions, signature, rlp

Here's a transaction to broadcast:

> f86c008504a817c80082520894e0defb92145fef3c3a945637705fafd3aa74a241880de0b6b3a7640000001ba009ebb6ca057a0535d6186462bc0b465b561c94a295bdb0621fc19208ab149a9ca0440ffd775ce91a833ab410777204d5341a6f9fa91216a6f3ee2c051fea6a0428

The error message is:

> Error: rlp: non-canonical integer (leading zero bytes) for uint64, decoding into (types.Transaction)(types.txdata).AccountNonce

Decoding the transaction the result is:

> {"nonce":0,"gasPrice":{"_bn":"4a817c800"},"gasLimit":{"_bn":"5208"},"to":"0xe0defb92145fef3c3a945637705fafd3aa74a241","value":{"_bn":"de0b6b3a7640000"},"data":"0x00","v":28,"r":"0x09ebb6ca057a0535d6186462bc0b465b561c94a295bdb0621fc19208ab149a9c","s":"0x440ffd775ce91a833ab410777204d5341a6f9fa91216a6f3ee2c051fea6a0428"}

What is wrong with the transaction?  Why does it have an error when it is broadcasted?

Answer (score 1):

The gas price, limit, and value are all unparsed from _bn (big number) when they should be a number. Not sure if that's happening when you decide the signed transaction or encode the unsigned transaction, but it's a good place to start to solve your issue.

Ps: please please please tell me you are on the testnets for these. Sending with a too high gas price could result in a very very expensive lesson.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/MOACChain/moac-core/issues/24

signed r and s need to clear leading zero bytes